# Pocket cube solver in Prolog

Tags: algorithm, recursion, prolog

Hello I have writtern this Prolog code to solve a scrambled 2x2 rubiks cube. Also known as a a pocket cube.

````
%the cube is represented as a fact with 24 arguments,
%where each argument represents the color of the sticker at that position.
%The Positions are according to cube_diagram.png

%Test scrambles:
%G_scramble := cube(y,y,y,y,r,r,b,b,w,w,w,w,o,o,g,g,b,b,o,o,g,g,r,r).
%G_scramble := cube(y,y,y,y,o,o,o,o,w,w,w,w,r,r,r,r,g,g,g,g,b,b,b,b).
%G_scramble := cube(b,y,g,o,r,b,o,o,w,y,o,r,r,w,w,b,r,y,w,g,y,b,g,g).
%G_scramble  := cube(y,y,y,y,r,g,r,r,w,w,w,w,g,o,o,o,b,b,b,b,o,r,g,g).

?-
    %The scramble to solve
    G_scramble := cube(b,y,g,w,w,b,r,b,y,y,g,b,o,r,w,o,y,r,w,g,o,g,o,r),
    
    write("the solution to the scramble is:"),nl,
    
    solve_layer_one(Solution,G_scramble, C),
    layer_one_solved(C),
    write(Solution),nl,
    
    orient_top(Solution2, C, X),
    top_oriented(X),
    write(Solution2),nl,

    permute_top(Solution3, X, Z),
    solved(Z),
    write(Solution3),nl.

side(up).
side(up_prim).
side(right).
side(right_prim).
side(front).
side(front_prim).
t_perm_or_up(t_perm).
t_perm_or_up(up).
sune_or_up(up).
sune_or_up(sune).

solved(
cube(C1,C1,C1,C1,C2,C2,C2,C2,C3,C3,C3,C3,C4,C4,C4,C4,C5,C5,C5,C5,C6,C6,C6,C6)).

layer_one_solved(
cube(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C7,C8,C8,C8,C8,C9,C10,C11,C11,C12,C13,C14,C14,C15,C16,C17,C17)).

top_oriented(
cube(C1,C1,C1,C1,C2,C3,C4,C4,C5,C5,C5,C5,C7,C8,C9,C9,C10,C11,C12,C12,C13,C14,C15,C15)).

%recursive predicate which finds the moves from scrambled cube to solved layer one.
solve_layer_one([], Cube, Cube).
solve_layer_one([NextRotation | Rotation], Cube, EndState) :-
    solve_layer_one(Rotation, CurrentState, EndState),
    rotateside(NextRotation, Cube, CurrentState),
    side(NextRotation).

%recursive predicate which finds the moves from cube with one layer solved to cube with one layer solve and top oriented.
orient_top([], Cube, Cube).
orient_top([NextRotation | Rotation], Cube, EndState) :-
    orient_top(Rotation, CurrentState, EndState),
    rotateside(NextRotation, Cube, CurrentState),
    sune_or_up(NextRotation).

%recursive predicate which finds the moves from cube with one layer solved and top oriented to solved cube.
permute_top([], Cube, Cube).
permute_top([NextRotation | Rotation], Cube, EndState) :- 
    permute_top(Rotation, CurrentState, EndState),
    rotateside(NextRotation, Cube, CurrentState), 
    t_perm_or_up(NextRotation).

%permutation of cube after rotating up side clockwise
rotateside(up,
cube(C1, C2, C3, C4,  C5,  C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C21, C22, C23, C24),
cube(C3, C1, C4, C2, C21, C22, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12, C17, C18, C15, C16,  C5,  C6, C19, C20, C13, C14, C23, C24)).

%permutation of cube after rotating up side anti-clockwise
rotateside(up_prim,
cube(C1, C2, C3, C4,  C5,  C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C21, C22, C23, C24),
cube(C2, C4, C1, C3, C17, C18, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12, C21, C22, C15, C16, C13, C14, C19, C20,  C5,  C6, C23, C24)).

%permutation of cube after rotating right side clockwise
rotateside(right,
cube(C1, C2, C3, C4, C5,  C6, C7, C8,  C9, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C21, C22, C23, C24),
cube(C1, C6, C3, C8, C5, C10, C7, C12, C9, C15, C11, C13,  C4, C14,  C2, C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C23, C21, C24, C22)).

%permutation of cube after rotating right side anti-clockwise
rotateside(right_prim,
cube(C1,  C2, C3,  C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C21, C22, C23, C24),
cube(C1, C15, C3, C13, C5, C2, C7, C4, C9,  C6, C11,  C8, C12, C14, C10, C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C22, C24, C21, C23)).

%permutation of cube after rotating front side clockwise
rotateside(front,
cube(C1, C2, C3,   C4, C5, C6, C7, C8,  C9, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C21, C22, C23, C24),
cube(C1, C2, C20, C18, C7, C5, C8, C6, C23, C21, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C16, C17,  C9, C19, C10,  C3, C22,  C4, C24)).

%permutation of cube after rotating front side anti-clockwise
rotateside(front_prim,
cube(C1, C2,  C3,  C4, C5, C6, C7, C8,  C9, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C21, C22, C23, C24),
cube(C1, C2, C21, C23, C6, C8, C5, C7, C18, C20, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C16, C17,  C4, C19,  C3, C10, C22,  C9, C24)).

%permutation of cube after doing the sune algorithm
rotateside(sune,
cube(C1 , C2,  C3, C4, C5,  C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C21, C22, C23, C24),
cube(C6 , C3, C22, C14, C2, C17, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12,  C5, C21, C15, C16,  C4, C13, C19, C20,  C1, C18, C23, C24)).

%permutation of cube after doing the t_perm algorithm
rotateside(t_perm,
cube(C1 , C2, C3, C4, C5,  C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12, C13, C14, C15, C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C21, C22, C23, C24),
cube(C1 , C2, C3, C4, C5, C22, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12, C21, C14, C15, C16, C17, C18, C19, C20, C13, C6, C23, C24)).
```
````